# Advice/ on how to plot side by side histograms with line graph going through in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet

I'm currently finishing off my Masters project and need to include some graphics for the write-up. Without boring you too much, I have some data which is associated with AR(1) parameters ranging from 0.1 to 0.9 by 0.1 increments. As such I thought of doing a faceted histogram like the one below (worry not about the hideous fruit salad of colours, it will not be used). [image: faceted histogram]

I used this code.

```
ggplot(opt_lens_geom,aes(x=l_1024,fill=factor(rho))) + geom_histogram()+coord_flip()+facet_grid(.~rho,scales = "free_x")
```

I also would like to draw a trend line for the median values since the AR(1) parameter is continuous. In a later iteration I deleted the padding and made it "look" like it was one graph, but I have had issues with the endpoints matching up since each facet is a separate graphical device. Can anyone give me some advice on how to do this? I am not particularly partial to the faceting so if it is not needed I do away with it.

I will try and upload sample data, but all simulating 100 values for each of the 9 rhos would work just to get it started like:

```
opt_lens_geom <- data.frame(rho= rep(seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1),each=100),l_1024=rnorm(900))
```

Comment: You need to upload the image; the current link is to your local drive. Please also include some example data and your code.

Comment: Fixed the plot issue, just grabbing the data and code.

Comment: I know its not solving your problem, but ````geom_density_ridges````  in ````ggridges```` is nice for seeing the trend across a range of distributions as the density plots can lay over each other slightly. Just a thought! Alternatively, just plot a regression with confidence intervals...

Comment: By "a trend line for the median values", you mean a line for the median of each value of rho? So there would be a median line in each facet, in your example chart?

Comment: I mean the medians should be joined by a line across the facets.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [ggridges](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html). I've assumed here that you want a median value for each value of `rho`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1001)
opt_lens_geom <- data.frame(rho = rep(seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), each = 100), 
                            l_1024 = rnorm(900))

opt_lens_geom %>% 
  mutate(rho_f = factor(rho)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(l_1024, rho_f)) + 
  stat_density_ridges(quantiles = 2, quantile_lines = TRUE)
```

Result. You can add `scale = 1` as a parameter to `stat_density_ridges` if you don't like the amount of overlap.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do a variant on this using `geom_violin` instead of using histograms, although you wouldn't get labelled counts, just an idea of the relative density. Example with made up data:

```
df = data.frame(
    rho = rep(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), each = 50),
    val = sample(1:10, 150, replace = TRUE)
)
df$val = df$val + (5 * (df$rho == 0.2)) + (8 * (df$rho == 0.3))

ggplot(df, aes(x = rho, y = val, fill = factor(rho))) +
    geom_violin() +
    stat_summary(aes(group = 1), colour = "black",
                 geom = "line", fun.y = "median")
```

This produces a violin for each value of rho, and joins the medians for each violin.

[image]

Comment: I had looked at violins, but the low number of counts in the tails made me wonder how to efficiently do binning. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It uses a pre-computed data frame of the medians.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris[c(1, 5)]
names(df) <- c("val", "rho")

med <- plyr::ddply(df, "rho", summarise, m = median(val))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = val, fill = factor(rho))) +
  geom_histogram() +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_vline(data = med, aes(xintercept = m), colour = 'black') +
  facet_wrap(~ factor(rho))
```

[image]

Comment: `+ theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "cm"))` is a good tweak for this if you don't like the spacing between facets

Comment: Yeah I had deleted the spacing between facets, it definitely helps for interpretability. my main issue has been how to link the medians across facets and have it look organic.